# How to preserve the uploaded files when redeploying the app with a different directory structure to DigitalOcean?

Tags: file, digital-ocean, directory-structure, redeploy, digital-ocean-apps

My app used to save the uploaded images into `public/images` folder. Now I've updated the directory structure and images are saved to `frontend/public/images`.

I'm afraid if I rebuild and redeploy the app on DigitalOcean after updating the repo to this structure, all the previously uploaded images will be gone.

How can I manage this process so that I don't lose the previous images ?

I thought of copying the old directory to local machine and moving images manually to the new location before deploying it, but I cannot find a way to copy the app directory on DigitalOcean to my local machine.